# UITableView scrolling get disturbed because of NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

Inside one class I have added an `UITableView` and a `NSTimer`.

When I'm trying to scroll `UITableView` its **freezing**.

If that `NSTimer` is not added, then the `UITableView` working just fine.

Here's my code for adding `NSTimer`

```
if (self.timer != nil)
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateClock)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Please suggest me any solution and What did I get wrong.

Comment: where you add this timer code? how it interact with your tableview ? please describe it for understand your question ..

Comment: I am adding timer Inside **viewDidLoad** and adding UITableView in **xib**. This timer for showing one Digital clock and tableView for showing some data.

Comment: you are calling your `updateClock` as often as possible because of the 0.0 timeInterval. If your are doing something on the main thread there, that is the reason why your UI freezes

Comment: ok then increase your time interval from 0.0. its freeze your view.

Comment: thank u very much for ur suggestion. now i make it to 0.1 interval its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call the timer  at least .1  second above or 1 second then your tableview of application will not struck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use timer for updating clock you can use this code:

https://github.com/nacho4d/ClockView

If you want to do perform other operations you can use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
});
```